# How to make content appear on wordpress visual/text editor?

Tags: wordpress, editor

So I'v made my website with visual studio and I didn't really use the visual or the text editor that wordpress provide.So for example now I have my homepage done, everything is there and everything looks perfect, but when I go to the visual/text editor of the page in the wordpress menu, it's blank.If I install elementor or some other plugin is pretty much the same.How I can make the content to appear in the page visual/text editor as well? I know that when i write something in the wordpress editor, it doesn't appear until i use the_content(); in loop, but I need pretty much the opposite.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the theme you have installed on wordpress, you will not get those contents in a text editor, you will need to customize it by navigating in Appearance - Customize there you will get flexible customization. Also, check which page is a front page by going to Setting - Reading.

Comment: I didn't installed any theme, I write my own from scratch.For now i change everything from Appearance - Customize or my writing software, but I want at least the text in visual/text editor to appear.Everything is fine in setting->reading.

Comment: Did you take any help from mobirise, template toast or Muse for making theme?

Comment: No, i tried to learn to do everything from scratch so it's all plain code.